# Intellij IDEA - Force each method parameter on its own line if more than one

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'd like to format my Java methods this way:

```
public void methodWithOneParameter(final String one) {
   ...
}

public void methodWithMultipleParameters(
     final String one,
     final String two) {
   ...
}
```

without considering the hard wrap setting. Is this possible?
I'm on `2018.2 EAP` (latest)

Comment: I think the "Wrap always" setting on "Method declaration parameters" does that. I think I'll delete this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy :)

> Settings (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces ->
>   Method Delceration Parameters -> (select) "wrap always"

You can also play with the 3 other options available. To have the exact code syntax that you asked for you need to select the `New line after "("` option.

[image]

Comment: I had found it, but anyway thanks for the confirmation! I'm going to remember your username for future consulting on formatting hahaha